# Set cookie defaults for express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to set the same `maxAge` and secure options for all `cookies` in my express 4 application.

Is there a way to express these defaults like the following pseudocode?:

```
app.set('cookieSettings', {secure: true, maxAge: 1000})
app.cookie('mySecureCookie, 'foo');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I'm afraid the only settings you can manipulate with `app.set()` are in this [list of application settings](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.settings.table). You can however pass an object of options to `res.cookie(name, value, options)` and reuse it whenever you set a cookie:

```
var cookieOptions = {
    maxAge: 10000
};

...

res.cookie('mySecureCookie', 'foo', cookieOptions);
```

Here is the [list of properties you can set](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.cookie) in the options object.